# Vungle Mediation Adapters not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

Getting the following error even after following proper documentation from Google Admob website:

```
06-29 18:30:04.705 7524-7549/? E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lcom/vungle/mediation/VungleExtrasBuilder;
                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Failed resolution of: Lcom/vungle/mediation/VungleExtrasBuilder;
                                        atcom.google.unity.mediation.vungle.VungleUnityExtrasBuilder.buildExtras(VungleUnityExtrasBuilder.java:31)
                                        at com.google.unity.mediation.vungle.VungleUnityInterstitialExtrasBuilder.buildExtras(VungleUnityInterstitialExtrasBuilder.java:8)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$d$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
                                        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$d.run(Unknown Source)
                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vungle.mediation.VungleExtrasBuilder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/<package-name>-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/d
```

My vungle-extras-library.jar file is also located in Assets/Plugins/Android folder and everything seems to run perfectly but when I launch the game it does not load mediation for Vungle and gives this internal error in logs.

Comment: Make sure the checkbox for Android is set in the inspector for the jar file. You can also unpack the apk with apktool or analyze it in Android Studio to make sure the classes are actually included.

Comment: The jar file is set for Android in inspector. I checked that. And this happens in the mediation tool directly downloaded from official admob mediation site. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing Unity Build system to internal and ran Play Services Resolver Force Resolve after doing so.